# Стоит ли учится писать unit тесты сейчас, если да, то стоит ли использовать библиотеки для тестирования?

Tags: php, тестирование, phpunit

Здравствуйте!
*Стоит ли учится писать unit тесты сейчас, если да, то стоит ли использовать* библиотеки для тестирования?
Уже целый день пытаюсь разобраться с установкой PHPUnit. Дело в том, что я не люблю черные ящики (когда я просто следую инструкциям и даже понятия не имею что происходит "под капотом"). Для меня PHPUnit - черный ящик. При этом я совсем новичок в PHP, но писать тесты хочется. Также не люблю что-то откладывать. Вот решил подыскать какую-нибудь библиотеку для тестирования. Стоит ли писать тесты, используя библиотеки? Если нет - то почему? Стоит ли использовать библиотеку или все таки PHPUnit лучше? Также стоит отметить что сложные тесты писать не требуется, а просто что-то типа проверки значений, возвращаемых той или иной функции.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не так сложно писать тесты как тестируемый код. Но по моему единственный способ заставить себя такое делать, это предъявить себе требование - 100% покрытие тестами.
Так что лучше научиться это делать раньше.

Answer (score 2):

### Ответ на ваши вопросы: Да

Тесты **всегда** стоит писать, если предполагается длительная разработка с дальнейшим развитием. Писать тесты на небольшие одноразовые утилиты и HTML визитки - пустая трата времени. Тестирование необходимо, чтобы внесение изменений в ваш код не привело к неправильной работе ПО в виде ситуации "исправил одну ошибку, появились другие".

PHPUnit идеально подходит для Unit тестирования.

*Конечно, если вы всегда пишете код без ошибок, обладаете идеальной памятью и даром предвидения - можете не писать.*

Answer (score 0):

Тесты стоит писать всегда. На мой взгляд лучше работать по методике **разработка через тестирование(TDD)**. Да, к такой методики надо привыкнуть? но и преимуществ у ней не мало. Я для себя отметил:

1. Тесты помогут определится более конкретно с архитектурой приложения
2. Избежать написание лишнего кода.
3. Уверенность что написание код завершено и работает правильно.